# python - if condition on missing datetime

Tags: python

I want to output a column where if Date contains date value then return 0 otherwise 1.

However, I am having trouble doing this on python.

I tried

```
if df['Date'] == 'NaT':
    df['Outcome'] = 0
else:
    df['Outcome'] = 1
```

[image]

Comment: _"I am having trouble doing this on python"_ Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). What trouble are you having? Include inputs, current outputs, full error stack traces if any.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The OP does include input and current output in his question. It is clear from the question that OP is getting the wrong output.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer so that others can see that the issue is resolved and find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in `np.where` function of numpy(in case you are ok with it), could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2['output']=np.where(df2['Date']=='NaT',0,1)
df2
```

***Explanation:*** Importing libraries of `numpy` and `pandas`. Created a DataFrame named `df2`. Then used `np.where` which has syntax like: `np.where(condition,value(when condition is TRUE),value(when condition is FALSE))`.